# Error while declaring variables in Mariadb

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I am using phpmyadmin in my (XAMPP server), when I try to declare a variable. I use to get syntax error.I have checked the syntax from other sources and it seems to be correct.
I have no idea why I am getting syntax error.
here is what I tried

```
 DECLARE Website VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'CheckYourMath.com';
```

Comment: How/where, exactly, are you trying to do this in XAMPP ... a stored procedure, a query, a trigger???

Comment: Inside XAMPP in a trigger

Comment: That line appears to be ok. Can you post the rest of the trigger (to the question, NOT in another comment) to know the entire trigger creation, as there might be something at another point.

Comment: And post the exact error message.  Check that you used `DELIMITER`.